# Retrieve the disabled attributes even after page refresh using localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have an HTML code with a select tag where the options are dynamically populated. Once the onchange event occurs the option selected gets disabled. And also if any page navigation happens the options populated previously are retrieved.

In my case once options are populated and any option is selected gets disabled( intention to not allow the user to select it again). So there might be a case where out of 3 options only two are selected and disabled so once I refresh and the options not selected previously should be enabled. And the options selected previously should be disabled. But my code enables all the options after refresh. How can I fix this?

**html code**

```
<select id="convoy_list" id="list" onchange="fnSelected(this)">
    <option>Values</option>
    </select>
```

**js code**

//This function says what happnes on option change

```
function fnSelected(selctdOption){
      var vehId=selctdOption.options[selctdOption.selectedIndex].disabled=true;
      localStorage.setItem("vehId",vehId);
      //some code and further process
}
```

//this function says the process on the drop-down list --on how data is populated

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
    //some requests and data sent
    //get the response back

    success:function(responsedata){
        for(i=0;i<responsedata.data;i++):
        {
            var unitID=//some value from the ajax response
            if(somecondition)
            {
                var select=$(#convoy_list);
                $('<option>').text(unitID).appendTo(select);
                var conArr=[];
                conArr=unitID;
                test=JSON.stringify(conArr);
                localStorage.setItem("test"+i,test);
            }
        }
    }
    });
}
```

//In the display function--on refresh how the stored are retrievd.

```
function display(){
for(var i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++){

    var listId=$.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("test"+i)));
    var select=$(#list);
        $('<option>').text(listId).appendTo(select);
}
}
```

In the display function the previously populated values for the drop down are retrieved but the options which were selected are not disabled. Instead all the options are enabled.
I tried the following in display function

```
if(localStorage.getItem("vehId")==true){
     var select=$(#list);
            $('<option>').text(listId).attr("disabled",true).appendTo(select);
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: one thing I see instantly: localStorage stores values as strings, so you should do the following `localStorage.getItem("vehId") == "true"`. true and "true" are not coerced to each other.

Comment: It does not work. It disables all the values in the drop-down but I want only the values which were disabled prev to be disabled back.

Answer (score 0):

Elements on your page shouldn't have same ids

```
<select id="convoy_list" onchange="fnSelected(this)">
    <option>Values</option>
    </select>
```

In your `fnSelected()` function you always store item `{"vehId" : true}` no matter what item is selected. Instead, you should for example first assign some Id to each `<option\>` and then save the state only for them.
For example:

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
    //some requests and data sent
    //get the response back

    success:function(responsedata){
        for(i=0;i<responsedata.data;i++):
        {
            var unitID=//some value from the ajax response
            if(somecondition)
            {

                var select=$("#convoy_list"); \\don't forget quotes with selectors. 
                var itemId = "test" + i;
                $('<option>').text(unitID).attr("id", itemId) \\we have set id for option
                                          .appendTo(select);
                var conArr=[];
                conArr=unitID;
                test=JSON.stringify(conArr);
                localStorage.setItem(itemId,test);
            }
        }
    }
    });
}
```

Now we can use that id in `fnSelected()`:

```
function fnSelected(options) {
    var selected = $(options).children(":selected");
    selected.prop("disabled","disabled");
    localStorage.setItem(selected.attr("id") + "disabled", true);
}
```

And now in `display()`:

```
function display(){
   for(var i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++){
       var listId = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("test"+i)));
       var select = $("convoy_list");
       var option = $('<option>').text(listId).id(listId);
                                 .appendTo(select);
       if(localStorage.getItem(listId + "disabled") == "true"){
         option.prop("disabled","disabled");
       }
       option.appendTo(select);
   }
}
```

Also maybe not intended you used following shortcut in your fnSelected:
          `var a = b = val;` 
        which is the same as `b = val; var a = b;`

So your fnSelected() function was equivalent to

```
function fnSelected(selctdOption){
      selctdOption.options[selctdOption.selectedIndex].disabled=true;
      var vehId = selctdOption.options[selctdOption.selectedIndex].disabled;
      localStorage.setItem("vehId",vehId); \\ and "vehId" is just a string, always the same.

}
```

Beware of some errors, I didn't test all of this, but hope logic is understood.